# eloquent relation with three tables in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have three Models named as `Job` , `JobDetail` and `Customer`.`Job` has many relation with `JobDetail` and `Customer` has many relation with `Job`. 
Below is the structure of tables.

```
Job
id customer_id jobname

JobDetail 
id job_id days

Customer 
id name
```

Below are the models:

```
class Job extends Model
{
    public function job_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobDetail','job_id','id');
    }

}

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job','customer_id','id');
    }
}

class JobDetail extends Model
{
    //
}
```

i was trying to execute the below query but its throwing error like `Call to undefined relationship [customer] on model [App\Job].`

My query :

```
 $data = Job::with(['job_details','customer'])->get();
```

Can some body suggest me how do i connect these models and get the data ?
Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify a relationship for `customer` in your `Job` model.

So, something like this should do the trick:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','job_id','id');
}
```